# I am getting a Python Selenium webdriver.get error and I cannot start Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I want to try automation using Selenium in python. I have installed Selenium 4.10.0 and change the webdriver and browser (Edge) to version 113.0.1774.35. I am using VSCodes in my MacBook.

This is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Edge('/Users/ME/Documents/Drivers/EdgeDriver/msedgedriver')

driver.get('https://www.google.com')

print('Press any key to continue...')
```

I am having an issue saying:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Timeout value connect was \<object object at 0x100800460\>, but it must be an int, float or None.
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'object'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/Users/aethelflaed/Documents/Coding Python/First_Selenium.py", line 2, in \<module\>
    driver=webdriver.Edge('/Users/ME/Documents/Drivers/EdgeDriver/msedgedriver')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Timeout value connect was \<object object at 0x100800460\>, but it must be an int, float or None.
```

Is there anything else I am missing to work with Selenium in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Note that the first argument is no longer `executable_path`, but `options`. (That's why you got the error.)

If you want to pass in an `executable_path`, you'll have to use the `service` arg now. This is how you should start Edge:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="PATH_TO_msedgedriver")
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Passing in the `executable_path` is optional. If it's not on your PATH, it will automatically get downloaded using the new selenium manager that's included.